# Missing in Eclipse key shortcut as in Visual Studio to go to definition F12 and come back Ctrl+F12

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio-2010

Is in eclipse the keys like F12 or Ctrl+F12 like in visual Studio?

F12 goes to definition of function or variable
Ctrl+F12 come back

I am using eclipse Kepler and vs2010

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use <kbd>F3</kbd> to go to the definition and <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> to go back. Tested in Eclipse Luna 4.4.1.